# Calling conventions and functions on parameter list

Tags: c++, c

I have the below two (related) questions.

1. Is the order of execution of functions called on other function's parameters list defined by C or C++ standard?
2. Does the actual calling convention used by the compiler influence the order of function execution in the below statement in C/C++?

   ```
   func1(func2(), func3());
   ```

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: No. Yes. No problem.

Comment: @texasbruce: I would like to say no, no. What makes you say calling convention affect execution order?

Comment: Why do you say "yes" to the second one?  I don't believe that stdcall, cdecl, pascal, register, or others define the order of evaluation of parameters.

Comment: The [evaluation strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy) determines the order of function execution.  The [calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) does not.

Comment: @texasbruce "No" is the wrong answer. The standard does *define it*, but says it's "unspecified". You're also wrong about the second part. See [calling convention and evaluation order](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4401929/3920237)

Comment: unspecified is the same as not defined for me. It is the same as 'do as you please' so not defined. Different compiler venders will do different things.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck [Unspecified means the standard "**defines**" a set of allowable behaviors"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior).

Comment: @remyabel might be but in the end you don't know what your compiler will do hence the result for you is undefined or you write compiler specific code.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck The point is that the behavior is defined by the **standard**, like the question asks.